# Using anova() on gamma distributions gives seemingly random p-values

Tags: r

I am trying to determine whether there is a significant difference between two Gamm distributions.  One distribution has (shape, scale)=(shapeRef,scaleRef) while the other has (shape, scale)=(shapeTarget,scaleTarget).  I try to do analysis of variance with the following code

```
n=10000
x=rgamma(n, shape=shapeRef, scale=scaleRef)
y=rgamma(n, shape=shapeTarget, scale=scaleTarget)
glmm1 <- gam(y~x,family=Gamma(link=log))
anova(glmm1)
```

The resulting p values keep changing and can be anywhere from <0.1 to >0.9.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Edit:  I use the following code instead

```
f <- gl(2, n)
x=rgamma(n, shape=shapeRef, scale=scaleRef)
y=rgamma(n, shape=shapeTarget, scale=scaleTarget)
xy <- c(x, y)
anova(glm(xy ~ f, family = Gamma(link = log)),test="F")
```

But, every time I run it I get a different p-value.

Comment: That looks very odd. You probably want to concatenate `y` and `x` and use that as the response variable in the model, and as the covariate (rhs of `~`), a factor that indicates membership to one or other of the distributions. `f <- gl(2, n)` gives the factor, `xy <- c(x, y)` gives the concatenated response, then `glm(xy ~ f, family = Gamma(link = log))`, but that is only looking at the expectation of \mu the "mean" of the distributions, if this is what then perhaps that is OK, but what about of moments of the distributions?

Comment: anova(glm(xy ~ f, family = Gamma(link = log))) does not give the p-value.  anova(gam(xy ~ f, family = Gamma(link = log))) gives the p-value but it keeps changing with different runs of x=rgamma(n, shape=shapeRef, scale=scaleRef) and y=rgamma(n, shape=shapeTarget, scale=scaleTarget) followed by xy <- c(x, y).  Thanks,

Comment: `anova.glm` **does** give the *p*-value if you instruct it which test, *F* or *ChiSq*, to do (you did read `?anova.glm` right?). You also realise that `rgamma()` is making pseudo random draws from those distributions? One would therefore *expect* the *p* value to vary depending on exactly what values were drawn for each of the two distributions. Finally - this isn't a question for [so]; flag your post to migrate it to [stats.se] as I'm not sure even my suggestion is really doing what you want.

Comment: I have edited my code to do what I think you are suggesting but still keep getting a different p-value for every run.  It is the difference in the means that I am interested in.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will indeed get a different p-value every time you run this, *if* you pick different realizations every time.  Just like your data values are random variables, which you'd expect to vary each time you ran an experiment, so is the p-value. If the null hypothesis is true (which was the case in your initial attempts), then the p-values will be uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Function to generate simulated data:

```
simfun <- function(n=100,shapeRef=2,shapeTarget=2,
                    scaleRef=1,scaleTarget=2) {
    f <- gl(2, n)
    x=rgamma(n, shape=shapeRef, scale=scaleRef)
    y=rgamma(n, shape=shapeTarget, scale=scaleTarget)
    xy <- c(x, y)
    data.frame(xy,f)
}
```

Function to run `anova()` and extract the p-value:

```
sumfun <- function(d) {
    aa <- anova(glm(xy ~ f, family = Gamma(link = log),data=d),test="F")
    aa["f","Pr(>F)"]
}
```

Try it out, 500 times:

```
set.seed(101)
r <- replicate(500,sumfun(simfun()))
```

The p-values are always very small (the difference in scale parameters is easily distinguishable), but they do vary:

```
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
hist(log10(r),col="gray",breaks=50)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks for showing this example Ben; had a packed afternoon and didn't have time to go into the detail you do here to get across the key point to the OP.